# Removing duplicate links from scraper I'm making

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, hyperlink, python-re

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


url = input("Please enter a URL to scrape: ")
r = requests.get(url)
html = r.text
print(html)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for link in soup.find_all('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^https://")}):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

down at the bottom, where it prints the link... I know it'll go in there, but I can't think of a way to remove duplicate entries there. Can someone help me with that please?

Comment: You can add the urls to a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) to remove dups.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) to remove duplicates. You call `add()` to add an item and if the item is already present then it won't be added again.

Try this:

```python
#!/usr/bin/python3

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = input("Please enter a URL to scrape: ")
r = requests.get(url)
html = r.text
print(html)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
urls = set()
for link in soup.find_all('a', attrs={'href': re.compile(r"^https://")}):
    urls.add(link.get('href'))
print(urls) # urls contains unique set of URLs
```

Note some URLs might start with `http://` so may want to use the regexp `^https?://` to catch both http and https URLs.

You can also use [set comprehension](https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-basics/python-set-comprehension/) syntax to rewrite the assignment and *for* statements like this.

```
urls = {
    link.get("href")
    for link in soup.find_all("a", attrs={"href": re.compile(r"^https://")})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of printing it you need to catch is somehow to compare.

Try this:

you get a list with all result by `find_all` and make it a set.

```
data = set(link.get('href') for link in soup.find_all('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^https://")}))

for elem in data:
    print(elem)
```